# Method not found exception (EventWaitHandle..ctor) using WinSCP .NET

Tags: .net, powershell, sftp, winscp, winscp-net

I am trying to connect to SFTP server using PowerShell, and using WinSCP .NET assembly.

Code is not able to open the session (`$session.Open($sessionOptions)`).

In the logs I found,

> `Exception: System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Void System.Threading.EventWaitHandle..ctor(Boolean, System.Threading.EventResetMode, System.String, Boolean ByRef, System.Security.AccessControl.EventWaitHandleSecurity)'.    at WinSCP.ExeSessionProcess.TryCreateEvent(String name, EventWaitHandle& ev)    at WinSCP.ExeSessionProcess.InitializeConsole()    at WinSCP.ExeSessionProcess.Start()    at WinSCP.Session.Open(SessionOptions sessionOptions) [2019-03-14 10:59:02.835Z] [0013]   Session.Cleanup entering [2019-03-14 10:59:02.835Z] [0013]     Terminating process`

Basically, it jumps from `$session.Open($sessionOptions)` to `$session.Dispose()` and skipping other part of code.

I tried to find solution here at WinSCP forum, but it didn't help:
https://winscp.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=26140

```
try {
    Add-Type -Path "M:\AMA\ztemp_powershell\WinSCPnet.dll" 

    $sessionOptions = New-Object WinSCP.SessionOptions -Property @{
        Protocol = [WinSCP.Protocol]::Sftp
        HostName = "abc.xyz.ca"
        UserName = "abc_abc"
        Password = "*********"
        SshHostKeyFingerprint = "ssh-rsa 2048 **********************"
        PortNumber = 22
    }
    $session = New-Object WinSCP.Session   
    $session.ExecutablePath = "H:\FromLocal\Powershell\WinSCP.exe" 
    $filelist = Get-ChildItem M:\AMA\ztemp_powershell\sample_files

    try {
        # $session.DebugLogPath = "M:\AMA\ztemp_powershell\sftp1.log"
        $session.Open($sessionOptions)

        $transferOptions = New-Object WinSCP.TransferOptions
        $transferOptions.TransferMode = [WinSCP.TransferMode]::Binary

        foreach ($file in $filelist) {
            $transferResult =  $session.PutFiles("M:\AMA\ztemp_powershell\sample_files\$file" , "/outbox/", $false, $transferOptions)

            foreach ($transfer in $transferResult.Transfers) {
                Write-Host "Upload of $($transfer.FileName) succeeded"
            }
        }
    }
    finally {
        $session.Dispose()
    }
    exit 0
}
catch {
    Write-Host "Error: $_"
    exit 1
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You are most probably using PowerShell 6 or newer (aka PowerShell Core). These versions of PowerShell use .NET (Core), not .NET Framework.

So you have to use the .NET Standard build of WinSCP .NET assembly. Inside the [`WinSCP-*-Automation.zip` package](https://winscp.net/eng/downloads.php#stable_automation), check the `netstandard2.0` folder.

Read

- [Installing the assembly for PowerShell](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_powershell#install);
- [Documentation for the error message you are getting](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/message_method_not_found_eventwaithandle).